# count distinct entries by summing values on a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how would you do this:

```
Tim   ...
Tim   ...
Henry  ...
Henry  ...
Henry ...
```

I have a table thatc ontains these names on the first column and I am interested in adding a new column X, that should have:

```
0.5
0.5
0.333
0.333
0.333
```

to count the number of distinct entries in the first column if you were to do the sum of the new column. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
select name,
  1.0 / count(name) over(partition by name) as X
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8e68/3)

Comment: Thank you so much, bluefeet, I had already tried the first variant of answer before I noticed yours, but yours is definitely very interesting as well, especially that I haven't used "partition" but for a couple of times! I am going to try this now!

Comment: great solution, tested also in case the table contains several columns, the select can ref to several ones!

Comment: @Sam You are welcome.  The nice thing about the `over()` is you do not have to use a `group by` clause with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
 [Name], 1.00/count(*) 
from YourTable 
group by [Name]
```

Sample:

```
declare @testTable table (Name varchar(10))

insert into @testTable
select 'A' UNION ALL
select 'A' UNION ALL
select 'A' UNION ALL
select 'B' UNION ALL
select 'B'

SELECT 
    [Name], 1.00/count(*) 
FROM @testTable 
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, techdo! I tried that and it worked wonders.